# WPGraphql IDE not showing when I activate Advanced Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wp-graphql

[image]When i activate the ACF plugin in my wordpress, the WPGraphqlIDE  shows the loading symbol, however, when i deactivate the Plugin, the WPGraphqlIDE shows. They were working initially.
These are the versions of my plugins, what do i need to do to fix the issue

```
 WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields 0.4.1
WPGraphQL Version 1.21.0
 Advanced Custom Fields Version 6.2.7
```